# Mavenising WebSphere/BPM tests and running via JUnit

Tags: maven, junit, ibm-bpm

We have a number of Unit Tests written using IID for the modules we've developed. We want them to run on our CI server

We use Maven for build sand JUnit to run the tests. Is there a way to *mavenise* BPM tests and run them via JUnit. If no then how could we implement a build and deploy to our CI server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can. Have a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/bpmjournal/1412_cai/1412_cai.html .

The solution you are looking for called **IBM Business Process Manager Testing Asset**.

There is one clue - you have to contact IBM Software Services for WebSphere to get it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have forwarded to our BPM guys. We'll see how they go.